# Jest snapshot testing fail in GitLab pipeline due to timezone mismatch

Tags: javascript, jestjs, gitlab, snapshot-testing

I have normal Jest snapshot tests for a component that calls `toDateString()` and `toTimeString()`.

The tests all pass when I run locally because both the tests and my component run in my current time zone (EST); however, when I check the tests into GitLab, the snapshot runs in EST, but the component calls the methods in Coordinated Universal Time, causing it to fail.

Is there a way to mock timezones in Jest? Or is there any other solution?

I am on Windows (not my choice).

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fix this issue adding `TZ=UTC` to my `.env` file. I'm using Mac though.